# newline and spaces in database column

Tags: python, postgresql, whitespace, where-clause

I cannot find the records using the WHERE CLAUSE :

```
SELECT sensor FROM table WHERE type = 'FEET'
```

There are records in the table whose 'type' column values are 'FEET', so I suppose it's something wrong about the format. the result would be something more than 'FEET' so that it simply can not find those equal to 'FEET'.

To find out what the records in column type looks like, I used the following codes to print them out:

```
    queryTem='SELECT type FROM tide_data'   
    curs.execute(queryTem)
    resultsTem=curs.fetchall()
    for resultTem in resultsTem:
        print resultTem
        print resultTem[0]
```

the resultTem turns out something like:

```
 ('FEET\n                         ',)
```

while resultTem[0] turns out like: FEET, which should be 'FEET\n'.Based on the information above, is there any way I can rewrite the WHERE CLAUSE statement and get the correct records? Since in the statement: WHERE a = value.. a should be a column name, I can not think of a way to do it.

Someone can help me out here? thanks..

Comment: Please update your question to show the data type of the `type` column; see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say """Since in the statement: WHERE a = value.. a should be a column name""". Not so, `a` can be any expression.

You say """the resultTem turns out something like: ('FEET\n ',) while resultTem[0] turns out like: FEET, which should be 'FEET\n'"". Instead of `print resultTem[0]`, use `print repr(resultTem[0])`. Get into the habit of using `repr()` in debug situations.

As others have pointed out, your data needs scrubbing. If there is an index on that `type` column, the trailing random whitespace will interfere with the indexing. If your database has a function (named e.g. STRIP) that works like Python's `str.strip()`, you should be able to fix it with a one-liner something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET type = STRIP(type) WHERE type != STRIP(type);
```

In the meantime, you can do a "startswith" type of query:

```
SELECT sensor FROM table WHERE type LIKE 'FEET%'
```

or use

```
SELECT sensor FROM table WHERE STRIP(type) = 'FEET'
```

**Further comments:**

(1) It looks like your output string is 30 characters wide (unless it got mangled by your pasting and my editing:

```
('FEET\n                         ',)
  .... v....1....v....2....v....3
```

One possible explanation for the extra spaces is that the column data type is `CHAR(30)`. If this is under your control you might like to change it to `VARCHAR(30)` or just `VARCHAR`. See [this section of the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-character.html) and note the "Tip" in the middle of the page.

(2) It seems there's no SQL function as easy as `str.strip()` for removing leading/trailing whitespace. In PostgreSQL you are going to need something like

```
TRIM(E' \r\n\t' FROM your_string_expression)
```

to remove leading and trailing spaces, carriage returns, line feeds, and tabs. See docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-string.html) (and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html); read section 4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-Style Escapes).

Comment: @John Machin: I tried the repr() and it comes out: 'FEET ..........                         '     so it is correct. Also, the LIKE statement seems working!!!!

Comment: @widget: see my further comments.

Comment: @John Machin: I used the LIKE .. statement and it simply works. Should I also try these other things? lol

Comment: @widget: LIKE is an operator, not a statement. You may like to try those other things if you are interested in cleaning up your mucky database or learning something instead of just grabbing the first kludge that floats past. lol ** 2. In fact, rotflmao.

Comment: @John Machin: Another thing is that, u said in WHERE a = value..  a can be any expression. Actually I tried that before, it's not giving me an error, but it just cannot find the records. so I thought it's probably allowed to use any expression, but if u don't use column here, then it probably cannot find the matching records.

Comment: @John Machin: about (1) of your further comments, I changed the column type to VARCHAR and it does work even I use WHRER  type = 'FEET'. This is a good tip. About (2), there actually is a function as str.strip(). just that i never used it before, and it works perfectly well. Anyway, after i changed the column type to VARCHAR, i dont have the extra space thing any more.

Answer (score 1):

resultTem[0] is not "FEET", it's "FEET\n". You'll need to scrub your data if you want your query to work.

Comment: that makes sense. it should be "FEET\n". i'll ask about the data

Comment: @widget: it's actually `'FEET\n.........................'` (where `.` is a placeholder for the spaces that SO removes), and it should be `'FEET'`.

Comment: @John: But aren't the trailing spaces ignored by `=` because they're just padding in a `char(n)` (rather than `varchar(n)`) column?

Comment: @mu is too short: That is true, **IF** the column is defined as `char(n)`. Using `char(n)` for variable length data is however suboptimal; see the tip in the middle of this page of PostgreSQL docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using a like keyword query.  Not as optimal but will work.

SELECT sensor FROM table WHERE type LIKE ‘%FEET%’

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you are inserting to your table, you didn't strip the endline (\n)

```
>>> a = ["FEET\n",]
>>> print a
['FEET\n']
>>> print a[0]
FEET

>>>
```

notice the extra line after feet.

you can just `select sensor from table where type="FEET\n"` if \n is always appended to feet in that column.

Comment: someone else loaded the data in, so i have no idea about that. the record came out like: ('FEET\n                         ',), a lot of space after \n.. so I have no idea if where type="FEET\n" would work or not. i'll try

Comment: You'd "notice the extra line" **and the subsequent spaces** if you were to use `repr()`

Comment: @John Machin Wasn't thinking too much into this answer... just quick and dirty. +1 your response.

Comment: Wasn't looking at the raw source of his question, either. See my edit.